# Binding a DropDownListFor to a variable list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

This works

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Assessment.Interviewer, Model.SiteListing)
```

This does not

```
<div class="resident-relationship">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.HouseholdMembersListing.ElementAt(i).Relationship, Model.ResidentTypeListing, new { @class = "t150"})</div>
```

How does one correct use @HTML.DropdownListFor to bind to a List<*anything*> so that on POST to the controller it will have the value?  I have this on a page where there can be many residents in the household.  I have other bindings like name and age and they work well.  But on the Relationship I need to have the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var ddlStates = '#dropdownlistId'  

$.ajax({
                cache:false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "@(Url.Action("GetStatesByCountryId", "Country"))",
                data: "countryId=" + selectedItem + "&addEmptyStateIfRequired=true",
                success: function (data) {
                    ddlStates.html('');
                    $.each(data, function(id, option) {
                        if( option.name=="Maharashtra")
                        {
                        ddlStates.append($('<option></option>').val(76).html(option.name));
                        }
                    });


                },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert('Failed to retrieve states.');
                    statesProgress.hide();
                }  
            });
```

Comment: Your answer should contains an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.